# Power BI rest api call getting 403 in postman

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azureportal

I am trying to call this power bi rest api using postman:

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/myreportid

I am passing Authorization key with Bearer + Token

but getting 403 even when I am calling from my application getting 403.

Any suggestion what I can do now. I have set power bi service with 10 delegated permission in azure portal. But no luck.

Comment: Decode your access token at https://jwt.io/ and post the contents in your question. Also it will be helpful if you post the response content, not only the status code.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do I need to pass username and password? I can see adal node js version using username and password js. .Net application also using user credential along with adal integration. Does adal.js support user credential or any suggestion?

Comment: To pass username and password where? I'm not familiar with adal.js, but in .NET you can generate token using AcquireToken methods either by passing username and password, or by prompting the user to select account and authenticate.

Comment: [Use the native app configuration to fetch the Bearer Token (Validate the scope)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkyze.png) [Select the Authorization type as Bearer Token and paste the token generated in previous step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OFb9.png)